# Does Python have built in string validation for Special Characters and/or Punctuation?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, validation

Python has `str.isalnum()`, `str.isdigit()`, `str.isupper()`, `str.islower()`, `str.isalpha()`, but does it have any built-in string validation checking for special characters or punctuation? (i.e. !@#$%^&*().,;'": ect)

Answer (score 5):

The standard `string` module provides [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation), which contains punctuation characters. You can test for membership in that:

```
def ispunct(ch):
    return ch in string.punctuation
```

Comment: yes, but this is for a single character, meaning, you'll need something like this for a string: `any([_ in string.punctuation for _ in 'asdf asd;fl a;sdlfk m$asdf asdfasdf'])`

Answer (score 0):

A one liner per @RickyLevi's comment:

```
any([ch in string.punctuation for ch in password])
```

and a `ispunct()` Function to check strings for ``` !"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_``{|}~ ```

```
import string

def ispunct(text):
  for ch in text:
    if ch in string.punctuation:
      return True
  return False

# >>> p = "password/"
# >>> ispunct(p)
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in function, but you can always build one.

This function checks user input for illegal characters (for naming files in Windows), cuts them out, notifies user and asks whether to submit a corrected string.

```
def infinite_char_check(string):
    """
    Check string against exclusion list, correct and ask to submit.

    Parameters
    ----------
    string : str

    Returns
    -------
    string : str
    """
    punctuation = ["|", "/", "\\", ":", "*", "?", '"', "<", ">"]
    the_same = string
    for symb in punctuation:
        string = string.replace(symb, "")
    if string != the_same:
        print()
        print(
            "Illegal characters detected! "
            'Please avoid using this set: /,\\,:,*,?,",<,>,|'
        )
        print("Corrected string: ", string)
        print(
            'Input "Y" (or "y") if you\'d like to change it, '
            "otherwise input any string"
        )
        spchk = input()
        if spchk in ("y", "Y"):
            print("Input experiment name")
            new_name = input()
            string = infinite_char_check(new_name)
    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing built-in. As others have noted, you'd have to write it.

Are you wanting to know if a string contains *any* punctuation, or if it contains *only* punctuation? If you want to know if a string is made up exclusively of punctuation characters, you can check that with this one-liner:

```
all(x in string.punctuation for x in your_string)
```

Examples of using this:

```
import string

all(x in string.punctuation for x in '$#!&')
# returns True
all(x in string.punctuation for x in 'foo!')
# returns False
```

Gottcha: it will also return `True` when given the empty string.

Answer (score -1):

Source: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2001-October/009454.html

```
import string
>>> print string.punctuation
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```