# How to get all the special characters as a list in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, list

How to get all non-alpha numeric characters in a string as a list?

Example input:

```
 spec!al Ch0racters are CO0l@!#
```

Desired output:

```
 ['!', ' ', '@', '#']
```

Comment: Whet do you call a "special character" ?

Comment: What do you mean in "special" characters?

Comment: What about string.punctuation? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html

Comment: If you have a set of common characters (not special characters) you could check if your input is inside them and all others would be special.

Comment: special character is not an alphabetic or numeric character like this  !@!$#

Comment: thank you @ThomasSchillaci  I got it

Comment: @Kamaraj Does your definition of "special" include whitespace (space, tab, newline etc.) characters? If yes, the answer is `string.whitespace+string.punctuation`. If not, @ThomasSchillaci got it right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have built in string validation for Special Characters and/or Punctuation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46355466/does-python-have-built-in-string-validation-for-special-characters-and-or-punctu)

Comment: @Kamaraj: I think you need to edit your question because of the ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

> ***Is it possible to get all the special characters in a specific string as a list in Python?***

If I understand you, that could help you:

```
string = "Special $#! characters   spaces 888323"
special_chars = list(set([e for e in string if not e.isalnum()]))
print(special_chars)

>>> ['#', ' ', '$', '!']
```

You can use [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum):

> ```
> S.isalnum() -> bool
>
> Return True if all characters in S are alphanumeric
> and there is at least one character in S, False otherwise.
> ```

If you insist on using regex, other solutions will do fine. However note that if it can be done without using a regular expression, that's the best way to go about it.

The Regex way is:

```
import re
print(list(set(re.sub('[A-Za-z0-9]+', '', string))))
```

Answer (score 5):

> ***Is it possible to get all the special characters available as a list in Python?***

You can use `string.punctuation`.

```
import string

print(list(string.punctuation))
#[!, ", #, $, %, &, ', (, ), *, +, ,, -, ., /, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, @, [, \, ], ^, _, `, {, |, }, ~]
```